# Force auto_increment to skip certain values?

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

As part of my current project, a URL might look like this:

```
http://example.com/summary/ab123
```

Where the last part is the integer ID after being run through what is effectively `base_convert(~,10,64)` with a custom alphabet.

However, letters spell things. For instance, when the ID 1,950,434 comes around, the URL will be:

```
http://example.com/summary/shit
```

So... yeah. Is there any way I can "reserve" the IDs that form undesirable words and make the `AUTO_INCREMENT` field skip past them?

Comment: Upvote this comment if you upvoted the question just because of the example URL :p

Comment: I actually genuinely thought it was a good question......

Comment: Are you base64 encoding *only* to get the length of the ID down? If not, you might be doing something wrong.

Comment: Why not just use the numeric form of the ID in the URL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While you could implement something in the database by creating a trigger that checks the ID that was auto-generated, and if that ID is included in your exclusion list - delete the row and try again.

But, this seems kind of hacky to me... and makes the database care about things that should be out of it's scope - IDs that translate to dirty words.

Instead, I would suggest a solution completely outside of the database.  For example, can you change your custom alphabet to exclude all vowels?  That way, regardless of the ID generated, it will never spell anything unsavory in your URL.

I could think of a lot of words that you wouldn't want in your URL.  If you try to blacklist the unwanted words, I'd say the odds are pretty good that a more exotic term would slip through... so I think an approach that doesn't require a blacklist would be ideal for this reason as well.

Comment: That's a very good idea. I shall implement it right away. Thank you very much!

Comment: _“For example, can you change your custom alphabet to exclude all vowels? That way, regardless of the ID generated, it will never spell anything unsavory in your URL.”_ RTFM, MTHRFCKR, CKCSCKR, … :-)

Comment: @CBroe Fair point, but cutting out the vowels prevents literally spelling them out and also greatly reduces the number of options. As a bonus, it means I can have "novelties" that have an ID alias containing vowels to spell specific words.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the only way to do this is to determine what the last ID is (using LAST_INSERT_ID).  Then determine if the next number would be an undesirable number, do a shim insert and then delete that entry immediately.